# How to "setWidgetSize" for Central Widget in SplitLayoutPanel?

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwtp

Ok, i have a `centralHTML` that was put inside the `<g:center>` of `mySplitLayoutPanel`.

In UiBinder:

```
<g:SplitLayoutPanel ui:field="mySplitLayoutPanel">
   <g:west size="200">
       <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="westHTML" />
   </g:west>
   <g:center>
       <g:HTMLPanel ui:field="centralHTML" />
   </g:center>
</g:SplitLayoutPanel>
```

This code works fine `mySplitLayoutPanel.setWidgetSize(westHTML,200)`

Ok, suppose the users drag the splitter to the right so that `centralHTML` becomes invisible. Then, to make the centralWidget visible we have to use :

```
mySplitLayoutPanel.setWidgetSize(centralHTML,200) // but this doesn't work
```

Some people say just set the size of the west Widget & the central one will automatically show up. But i don't want to do that, instead i just want to set the widget size of the central widget only. So,

How to "setWidgetSize" for Central Widget in SplitLayoutPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the size of the center area in [SplitLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SplitLayoutPanel.html) or in [DockLayoutPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html), you can only set sizes of the edge children, from the javadoc:

`A panel that lays its child widgets out "docked" at its outer edges, and allows its last widget to take up the remaining space in its center.`

This behavior makes sense, otherwise the dock-layout panel must have a way to select edge widgets to reduce their size and this could be worst.

I would use an `onResize` handler to know when a widget is resized and restore sizes someway.

Comment: ok, that makes sense, thank you very much for ur info. I use onResize then.